# Why does my Webmin only show 1 CPU and only half my RAM?

Tags: server

This is not answered by "Why does Ubuntu only show 3GB of RAM?"

I have 6x "HPE 8 GB 2Rx4 PC3-10600R-9" RAM sticks installed across 2 banks in my HP DL360 G6 but I only see 24GB.
It was showing up correctly in ubuntu 16. Ive been on ubuntu 18 for a while now but I only just noticed its not working properly anymore.

Question, why?.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

free

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          24670         480       23836           2         353       23854
Swap:         50319           0       50319
```

free -m

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache available
Mem:          24092         474       22898           2         719       23286
Swap:         49139           0       49139
```

free --mega

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          24670         480       23836           2         353       23854
Swap:         50319           0       50319
```

In addition, my webmin used to show both CPU's but now only shows 1. Not sure why this is but if anyone could also shed some light on this, is it intended?

sudo lshw | grep -i cpu

```
 *-cpu:0
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5550 @ 2.67GHz
      capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida flush_l1d

 *-cpu:1
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
      bus info: cpu@1
      version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5550 @ 2.67GHz
      capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida flush_l1d
```

More info:

An examination of the bios revealed only 24GB of memory being detected. I attempted swapping the memory between slots and found that only 1 cpu bank of ram is being detected. Are there any settings which might cause this?

Update:

I just tried;

```
    CPU 1                CPU 2
(A) 8G, (B) 8G      (A) 8G, (B) 8G
```

The result was 16GB, it's just not picking up the RAM for CPU 2.

I also tried switching between mirrored and lockstep for this configuration but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 16 or 18. Might you mean 18.04?

Comment: Did you show the output of `free -m` in your post? Please edit to reflect this. I'm curious if it's only webmin that reports 24GB or `free` reports this as well.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I have updated it with the new info you requested.
David Yes, I didn't think anyone would mind me shortening it.

Comment: Ubuntu has both *yy* products (they are *snap* only, eg. Ubuntu Core 16, Ubuntu Core 18) so I take it you're using a *snap* only release of Ubuntu; however your paste shows a regular Ubuntu desktop or Server (18.04.5 is not a *snap* only release as it uses the *yy.mm* format).   Ubuntu releases using *yy* are different products to the *yy.mm* standard releases.

Comment: @guiverc Oh so the versioning for ubuntu is actually the release date yy.mm.dd? I had no idea and I thought it was a normal versioning system. Makes total sense now thanks for the info. PS: I just re-read that and sorry if it seems a little sarcastic, I didn't mean it to. I genuinely didn't know that.

Comment: have you gone back to basics, and looked at how much memory is seen in BIOS? How many CPUs seen by BIOS? have you tried memtest86? (note: myself, I can no longer get memtest86 as a boot option, so I use a bootable USB stick with only memtest86 on it.)

Comment: @DougSmythies I just updated my question. I tested my RAM sticks and they work. I checked bios and it appears the ram in the right hand bank ie for 1 of the CPU's is not showing up. 1 stick in each bank shows 8gb whereas 2 sticks in the left bank shows 16gb.

Comment: FYI: The *yy.mm* part is, the extra digit is a point release or detail that shows update level, eg. 18.04.5 is the 2018-April release with .5 upgrade level.  LTS releases have two kernel choices, if using GA kernel it'll mean 4.15 for any upgrade point release, but if using HWE the .5 means you're using the 5.4 HWE kernel (18.04.4 used 5.3, 18.04.3 used 5.0 etc).  IoT/device/appliance/cloud releases have only a single release per year so no need to use month (and point releases make no sense with *snap* packages)

Comment: Could it be caused by memory mirroring? I did replace the CMOS battery about a year ago.

Comment: I just checked and it's set to Advanced ECC, i don't know if that is like mirroring or anything.